# handling missing entries in regression modeling in R

Tags: r

I have a table, which has missing value entries that are either marked as NA or just empty cell. I read this table as

```
test<-read.csv("test.csv",sep=",",header=T)
```

The resulting `test` data set has sth like

```
column1  column2    column3
NA                   1
```

the `NA` in column1 comes from the `NA` from the original csv file. The empty cell in column2 is because original csv entry is empty. How to handle this in fitting linear regression model in R.

Comment: The `read.csv` parameter `na.strings` allows you to specify what is to be interpreted as NA. By default, it does include "NA", so I suspect `column1` is of class `character` while `column2` is `numeric`. Then you'd have nothing to worry about. Doing `str(test)` will tell you what class your columns are.

Comment: Once you determine the class, you can change all blank cells to NA if it makes you feel better, and, of course, these rows (obs) will be omitted from any regression model.

Comment: If I were a betting man, I would say that the value in column2 is a factor of level `""`. You have two options. Either search and replace the empty string prior to importing the data into R, or change factor level (assuming I'm right in my first statement and column2 is suppose to be a factor) to NA.

Comment: If @Roman is right and "" is a factor level, you could simply add `na.strings = c("","NA")` when calling `read.csv`. Then "" would become <NA>, not a new level.

Comment: @DominicComtois thanks, I was too lazy to try if `na.string` takes a vector of length > 1 or not.